# RNN Input Dimension! Pytorch

Tags: pytorch, recurrent-neural-network, tensor

having hard time to input the data into RNN in pytorch..
The output dimension from my previous linear layer is (32,50) where 32 is batch size.

I want to feed this to RNN layer.
I tried reshaping my data in 2 forms: [32,1,50] and [32,50,1] both of the times I get error.

```
class trainer:
    def __init__():
       self.r = nn.RNN(input_size= 50, hidden_size=2, num_layers = 3, batch_first=True)
    
    def forward(self):
       previous_layer_output 
       previous_layer_output.unsqueeze_(-1) Makes shape [32,50,1] # I also tried 
     #previous_layer_output.unsqueeze_(1) makes shape [32,1,50]
       
       rnn = self.r(previous_layer_output )
```

I get this error : **RuntimeError: input.size(-1) must be equal to input_size. Expected 50, got 1**

If i do **previous_layer_output.unsqueeze_(1)** I get the below error:
**ValueError: Expected target size (32, 50), got torch.Size([32])**

Answer (score 0):

To distill and isolate your problem, I wrote this code.

```
import torch 
from torch import nn

rnn = nn.RNN (input_size=50, hidden_size=2, num_layers=2, batch_first=True) 
a = torch.rand(32, 50)   
a.unsqueeze_(1) 
o = rnn(a)
```

and it worked fine for me. I am not sure what is the problem but it might be somewhere else in your code.